# How to look for specific letters in a string inside an array with JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say for example I have a array like this

```
var array = ['Value1', "ThisIsValue2", "AndThisIsValue3"]
```

I want to be able to check this array to look for the word And but nothing more once it checks all the values and it finds the one with the word And I want it to take that whole value and save it to another variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Like a combination of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)?

Comment: what do you want to happen if And is found more then once?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you so much

Comment: np, I moved it to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, use array filter with [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

`let result = array.filter(v => v.includes('And'))`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to search in the array the word that contains "And" and return the whole word.

Easy way but not precise: search the word that contains "And" within any place in the string (ex "**And**ThisIsValue3", "This**And**That")

```
let result = array.find(w => /And/.test(w));
```

You can define the regular expression that fits fine with your purpose.

The variable result will store the **first** word that matches the regExp or undefined if no one does. If you need all matches, just use array.filter in the same way.